# Install Matlab on Manjaro

Tags: matlab, manjaro

I am trying to install Matlab on Manjaro, but after I run the script "install", I got error: `...Downloads/matlab_R2020a_glnxa64/bin/glnxa64/libexpat.so.1: file too short`

Does anyone know how can I fix it?

Comment: I download and tried matlab 2019b, it works. Thus I think R2020a doesn't support arch  until now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use root as the ID for the Matlab. Otherwise, the key recognition may cause errors.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

From the matlab aur package:

Maybe you'd create this archive like this:

1) download the matlab installer form themathworks, let's imagine that file is ~/Downloads/matlab_R2019b_glnxa64.zip

2) extract it: unzip ~/Downloads/matlab_R2019b_glnxa64.zip -d ~/matlab

3) run the installer almost completely through manually: ~/matlab/install -downloadFolder ${HOME}/matlab/dl -destinationFolder ${HOME}/matlab/deleteme

you must enter all your proper license info here, the purpose of this is to get the toolbox files you'll need for the offline install later when you see that the installer has finished downloading everything, press the Cancel button in the gui and end the installer early you don't really want the installer to extract/decrypt the files it has downloaded

4) delete anything that might have started to be installed in the above step: rm -rf ~/matlab/deleteme

5) now you can create the tarball you'll need here: tar -cvf matlab.tar -C ~/matlab/ .

You can get your file installation key (that you must manually put into matlab.fik) from https://mathworks.com/licensecenter

Then maybe you could make the matlab.fik file you need for this package like this:

echo "xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-..." > matlab.fik